# python log formatter that shows all kwargs in extra

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

I hope to add the following log points to my application and display the full contents of `extra` on console, e.g.,

```
logger.info('Status', extra={'foo':data})
logger.info('Status', extra={'bar':data})
logger.info('Status', extra={'foo':data, 'bar':data})
```

and I hope to see:

```
2016-10-10 15:28:31,408, INFO, Status, foo=data
2016-10-10 15:38:31,408, INFO, Status, bar=data
2016-10-10 15:48:31,408, INFO, Status, foo=data, bar=data
```

Is this even possible?  According to official logging documentation, the `Formatter` must be set up with a format string that expects `foo` and `bar` but in my case all I want is to dump out the entire kwargs of `extra` without prior knowledge of `foo` and `bar`.

Comment: Take a look at https://bugs.python.org/file4410/logging.py. I don't have time to work out a full example, but I think you could abuse the args attr on the LogRecord and just pass in a dict.

Answer (score 6):

Trying to solve the same problem right now. The problem is that anything passed to extra is added as a property of LogRecord and the formatter cannot distinguish it from other LogRecord properties. I only came up with a hackish approach of creating a dummy record and comparing it with the actual one:

```
class ExtraLogFormatter(logging.Formatter):                                                                             
    def format(self, record):                                                                                           
        dummy = logging.LogRecord(None,None,None,None,None,None,None)                                                   
        extra_txt = ''                                                                                                  
        for k,v in record.__dict__.items():                                                                             
            if k not in dummy.__dict__:                                                                                 
                extra_txt += ', {}={}'.format(k,v)                                                                      
        message = super().format(record)                                                                                
        return message + extra_txt
```

Answer (score 6):

Entries of the object passed as `extra` will become member variables of the LogRecord.

```py
logger.info('Status', extra={'my_params':{'foo':3, 'bar':4}})
```

Then you can format it as:

```py
handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(message)s %(my_params)s'))
```

Which will result in the following log:

```
#> Status {'foo':3, 'bar':4}}
```

This assumes you have control over the 'extra' parameter at the time of logging.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to define a simple utility function:

```
def extra(**kwargs):
    return {"extra": kwargs}
```

Then your usage:

```
logger.info('Status', extra={'foo':data, 'bar':data})
```

Becomes not too different:

```
logger.info('Status', **extra(foo=data, bar=data))
```

And you can set the formatting easily:

```
handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(message)s %(extra)s'))
```